ASP.NET MVC Double with Dot Decimal separator get comma separator once supplied in html form
i'm stuck and cannot find easy way to solve this issue, let's suppose i have below model:
public class FooModel
{
  string name{get;set;}
  double doubleFoo{get;set}
}

i built a class, usable from a HTMLform, where user can upload an excel file, and this class will read values to create a new fooObject, with properties like FooModel.
FooModel FooObjectFromExcelValues = new FooModel()
{
 name = nameFromExcel,
 doubleFoo = doubleFooFromExcel, /* <= this variable contains dot decimal separation, and look like "0.061065380952380954" */
}

I have checked, FooObjectFromExcelValues.doubleFooFromExcel is dot separated value.
Now, my controller return a view, where a form is populated with values sent from FooObjectFromExcelValues.
<form asp-action="FooAdd">

<div>
<label asp-for="name" class="control-label"></label>
<input asp-for="name" class="form-control"/>
<span asp-validation-for="name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div>
<label asp-for="doubleFoo " class="control-label"></label>
<input asp-for="doubleFoo " class="form-control"/>
<span asp-validation-for="doubleFoo " class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

</form>

form once populated with object sent from excel
here come the trouble, doubleFoo is now showed on my form with comma separation like "0,061065380952380954", and i can't send the form to add object to database.
Why ? How can i easily solve this ?
tried several from stackoverflow without success

In your controller, convert the double value to a string with a dot as the decimal separator before passing it to the view.

that would be an idea but my view is waiting to receive an object of type FooModel, so i can't have doubleFoo as string type

Try the solution I provided, as you may know sometime locale settings of your system or browser, which might affect how decimal numbers are displayed and processed.


doubleFoo is now showed on my form with comma separation like
"0,061065380952380954", and i can't send the form to add object to
database.
Why ? How can i easily solve this ?

Well, in some locales, commas are used as decimal separators instead of dots. This discrepancy causes issues when the form data is sent back to the server, as the server expects a dot-separated decimal value.
I order to fix the issue,  in the controller, convert the double value to a string with a dot as the decimal separator before passing it to the view. This ensures that the correct format is displayed in the form.
You could do as following:
var fooObjectFromExcelValues = new FooModel
{
    name = "Sample Name",
    doubleFoo = 0.061065380952380954
};


ViewBag.DoubleFooString = fooObjectFromExcelValues.doubleFoo.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

View:
@model FooModel

<form asp-action="FooAdd" method="post">
    <div>
        <label asp-for="name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label asp-for="doubleFoo" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="doubleFoo" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.DoubleFooString" />
        <span asp-validation-for="doubleFoo" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

When you would submit the from value, you could cross check the correct value once again:
if (double.TryParse(model.doubleFoo.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double parsedDouble))
{
    model.doubleFoo = parsedDouble;

    // Simulate adding the object to the database
    // db.FooModels.Add(model);
    // db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
}

Output:


Note: Please refer to this official document for additional information.

It is working thank you. But since i have a lot of variable, there would be a lot of "viewbag" ?
I found a javascript function that could be put on form directly, see below. Would it be an easier solution ? Also , i'm able to achieve this script only when user focus on input form and try change something => have you any idea how this script could work when page is loaded with fooObjectFromExcelValues values ?


Thanks for the update, sure you could also use javascript if you want. If don't want to use viewBag you could rebind the value into your model as well, my intention was to share idea how you could fix the issue. Either approach you could consider.

I tried using Javascript, in the end, even if i achieved to transform all values to Dot decimal, my form still doesn't work the way i want. Either it is not accepting input since my form wait for text values, or, if i change "type = number", values disappear from form because form receive values with comma at first (before javascript change it to dot). Could you please elaborate the solution of rebinding value ? Thank you very much

If you could manage in backend code that would be great, other than, in client side new trouble might introduce which you are getting. Would it be possible to post new question with the problem you are having now, so that it can be checked individually.
